How to filter clearML jobs by started date in specific time range
from allegroai.backend_api.services.v2_13.tasks import GetAllRequest

task_query_qwargs = {"started": ["2024-04-30T21:00:00", "2024-05-02T21:00:00"]}
GetAllRequest(task_query_kwargs)

I am trying something like this and getting: ValueError: Unsupported keyword argument: started
I see also this option:
from allegro_utils.tasks import
iterate_task_objects_since(last_time_stamp: datetime.datetime,
task_query_qwargs)
but in this function the filtering of time stamp is after getting all jobs from clearML, I need to filter by strted in get request from clearML and not after
because I have a big data of jobs in clearML and request action take a long time.
Is there any way to filter clearML jobs by started date in the level of   clearML request?

The GetAllRequest is an internal request object, and is not recommended for direct use.
Instead, you can use the APIClient (see here) _allow_extra_fields_: true to allow the started field to be used:
from clearml.backend_api.session.client import APIClient
client = APIClient()
tasks = client.tasks.get_all(started=["2024-04-30T21:00:00", "2024-05-02T21:00:00"], _allow_extra_fields_=True)

Even better, you can also use the SDK itself by calling Task.query_tasks() to get task IDs or Tasks.get_tasks() to get task objects, like so:
from clearml import Task

# Get a list of task IDs matching query
task_ids = Task.query_tasks(task_filter={
    "started": ["2024-04-30T21:00:00", "2024-05-02T21:00:00"],
    "_allow_extra_fields_": True
})

# Get a list of task objects matching query
tasks = Task.get_tasks(task_filter={
    "started": ["2024-04-30T21:00:00", "2024-05-02T21:00:00"],
    "_allow_extra_fields_": True
})

Disclaimer: I am a member of the ClearML staff
